# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'userapp'@'localhost' / glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish, asadmin

I'm trying to use a javax.sql.DataSource injected into a servlet (glassfish)

```
@Resource (name="jdbc/MysqlDS" )
javax.sql.DataSource mysqlDS;
```

The following statements fail, throwing *"java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'userapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"*:

```
con=mysqlDS.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select now()");
```

or

```
con=mysqlDS.getConnection("userapp","userpassword");
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select now()");
```

But the following were successful:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_lindenb", "appuser", "userpassword");
w.println("OK");
con.close(); con=null;
```

or

```
con=mysqlDS.getConnection("root","root_password");
```

or

```
con=mysqlDS.getConnection("me","mypassword");
```

or

```
$ mysql -u appuser --password=userpassword -D user_lindenb -e 'select now()'
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-05 10:19:07 |
+---------------------+
```

The grant was declared as follow:

```
 grant insert,select,update,delete on user_lindenb.* TO 'appuser'@'localhost' identified by 'userpassword';
```

and the resources were declared as follow

```
asadmin --port  8138 create-jdbc-connection-pool \
            --datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource \
            --restype javax.sql.DataSource \
            --property "password=userpassword:user=userapp:serverName=localhost:databaseName=user_lindenb" \
             MysqlDS
asadmin --port 8138 create-jdbc-resource \
            --connectionpoolid MysqlDS \
            "jdbc/MysqlDS"
```

what's wrong with this user 'userapp' ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I added

```
grant USAGE on *.* TO 'appuser'@'localhost' identified by 'adminadmin';
```

everything worked  fine... I don't understand why.